# screen resizing and element position adjustement

Tags: html, css

below you can see a link to a page that when reduced to a width of 940 px and lower, is suppose to hide the menu and instead, show a drop-down menu instead. The problem is when screen size is reduced, the elements get misaligned. what I want is to keep the drop down menu, the red rectangle and the search bar in one line, regardless of the screen size

here is the related css:

```
nav select {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 940px) {
  nav ul     { display: none; }
  nav select { display: inline-block;margin-left: 300px; margin-top: -10px; }
}
```

here is the full code:

https://codepen.io/slackk/pen/RpNBvO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When designing, you start off building mobile website first.
however, back on topic, your are closing  tag by the end, but it is starting at the middle of the document. Are you sure you placed it correctly?

Comment: thanks for reply, I don't understand exactly what you mean. where should I place the tag?

Comment: This is what should branching look like on https://jsfiddle.net/drazenbaric/b2g5bfxs/ but in your code you open second tag by the fourth and close it by the end

Comment: could you specify the line numbers

Comment: Ok, delete display:none and add background-color:yellow to nav select style. You will see what I am talking about, positioning is bugged. (fu*ked)